# Limited horizontal ticks in D3js v4 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to reduce the number of ticks in the x-axis due to overlapping values.

[image]

First I tried by setting up manually a limited number of axis by using `.call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10));` but no results. I tried also to use an interval of four days between ticks : `.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(dateFormat).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(4)));` but still not working.

Any ideas please ?

```js
function stacked_bar_chart_d3js(data, size_width, size_height, id_chart, data_groups) {

  var input = {
      'data': data,
      'width': size_width,
      'height': size_height,
      'id_chart': id_chart,
      'data_groups': data_groups,
    },
    canvas = setUpSvgCanvas(input);

  drawBars(input, canvas);

  function drawBars(input, canvas) {
    var params = {
      'input': input,
      'canvas': canvas
    };
    initialize(params);
    update(params);
  }

  function initialize(params) {

    // unpacking params
    var canvas = params.canvas,
      input = params.input;

    // unpacking canvas
    var svg = canvas.svg,
      width = params.width = canvas.width,
      height = params.height = canvas.height;

    // processing Data and extracting binNames and clusterNames
    var formattedData = formatData(input.data, input.data_groups),
      blockData = params.blockData = formattedData.blockData,
      binNames = params.binNames = formattedData.binNames,
      clusterNames = params.clusterNames = formattedData.clusterNames;


    // initialize color
    var color = setUpColors()
      .domain(clusterNames);

    // initialize scales and axis
    var scales = initializeScales(width, height),
      x = scales.x,
      y = params.y = scales.y;

    x.domain(binNames);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(blockData, function(d) {
      return d.y1;
    })]);

    initializeAxis(svg, x, y, height, width);

    // initialize bars
    var bar = params.bar = svg.selectAll('.bar')
      .data(blockData)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bar');

    bar.append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr('y', function() {
        return y(0);
      })
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', 0)
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.cluster);
      });

    var bar_label = params.bar_label = svg.selectAll('.bar_label')
      .data(params.input.data)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bar_label');

    bar_label.append('text')
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return (x(d.period) + (x.bandwidth() / 2));
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d3.sum(d3.values(d))) - 8;
      })
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr('style', 'font-size:10px')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d3.format("$")(d3.sum(d3.values(d))
          .toFixed(2));
      })
      .style({
        fill: 'black'
      });

    // heights is a dictionary to store bar height by cluster
    // this hierarchy is important for animation purposes
    // each bar above the chosen bar must collapse to the top of the
    // selected bar, this function defines this top
    params.heights = setUpHeights(clusterNames, blockData);

    // defining max of each bin to convert later to percentage
    params.maxPerBin = setUpMax(clusterNames, blockData);

    params.view = false;

  }

  function update(params) {
    // retrieving params to avoid putting params.x everywhere
    var svg = params.canvas.svg,
      y = params.y,
      blockData = params.blockData,
      width = params.width,
      height = params.height,
      bar = params.bar,
      bar_label = params.bar_label;

    var transDuration = 700;

    // update Y axis
    y.domain([0, d3.max(blockData, function(d) {
      return d.y1;
    })]);

    var axisY = d3.axisLeft(y)
      .ticks(4, ".2s")
      .tickSize(-width);

    svg.selectAll('.axisY')
      .transition()
      .duration(transDuration)
      .call(axisY);

    // update bars
    bar.selectAll('rect')
      .transition()
      .duration(transDuration)
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return y(d.y1);
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return height - y(d.height);
      });

    bar_label.selectAll('text')
      .transition()
      .duration(transDuration)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d3.sum(d3.values(d))) - 8;;
      })
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr('style', 'font-size:10px')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d3.sum(d3.values(d)) > 0.00 ?
          d3.format("$")(d3.sum(d3.values(d)).toFixed(2)) :
          "$0.00";
      });
  }

  // heights is a dictionary to store bar height by cluster
  // this hierarchy is important for animation purposes
  function setUpHeights(clusterNames, blockData) {
    var heights = {};
    clusterNames.forEach(function(cluster) {
      var clusterVec = [];
      blockData.filter(function(d) {
          return d.cluster == cluster;
        })
        .forEach(function(d) {
          clusterVec.push(d.height);
        });
      heights[cluster] = clusterVec;
    });
    return heights;
  }

  // getting the max value of each bin, to convert back and forth to percentage
  function setUpMax(clusterNames, blockData) {
    var lastClusterElements = blockData.filter(function(d) {
      return d.cluster == clusterNames[clusterNames.length - 1];
    });
    var maxDict = {};
    lastClusterElements.forEach(function(d) {
      maxDict[d.x] = d.y1;
    });
    return maxDict;
  }

  function initializeScales(width, height) {

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .padding(0.7);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    return {
      x: x,
      y: y,
    };
  }

  function initializeAxis(svg, x, y, height) {
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
      .ticks(4, ".2s");

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axisY')
      .call(yAxis);

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axisX')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  }


  function setUpSvgCanvas(input) {
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 100,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 45
      },
      width = input.width - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = input.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select(input.id_chart)
      .append("svg")
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    return {
      svg: svg,
      margin: margin,
      width: width,
      height: height,
    };
  }

  function setUpColors() {
    return d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
  }

  // formatting Data to a more d3-friendly format
  // extracting binNames and clusterNames
  function formatData(data, data_groups) {
    var clusterNames = d3.values(data_groups);
    var binNames = [];

    var blockData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var y = 0;
      binNames.push(data[i].period);
      for (var j = 0; j < clusterNames.length; j++) {

        var height = typeof data[i][clusterNames[j]] === "undefined" ? 0 : parseFloat(data[i][clusterNames[j]]);

        var block = {
          'y0': parseFloat(y),
          'y1': (height === 0) ? parseFloat(y) : parseFloat(y) + parseFloat(height),
          'height': height.toFixed(2),
          'x': data[i].period,
          'cluster': clusterNames[j],
        };

        y += parseFloat(height);
        blockData.push(block);
      }
    }
    return {
      blockData: blockData,
      binNames: binNames,
      clusterNames: clusterNames,
    };

  }
}

var data = {
  "column_chart_data": [{
      "period": "2020-10-28",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-27",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-26",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-25",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-24",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-23",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-22",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-21",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.21,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-20",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-19",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-18",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-17",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-16",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-15",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-14",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-13",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-12",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-11",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-10",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-09",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-08",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-07",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0.99,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-06",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0.31,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-05",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-04",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-03",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-02",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-10-01",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
      "rghm": 0.01,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-30",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.23,
      "rghm": 0.43,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-29",
      "Autres": 0,
      "defaultresourcegroup-par": 0,
      "demouic": 0.51,
      "rghm": 0.68,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-28",
      "Autres": 0,
      "defaultresourcegroup-par": 0,
      "demouic": 0.5,
      "rghm": 0.68,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-27",
      "Autres": 0,
      "defaultresourcegroup-par": 0,
      "demouic": 0.5,
      "rghm": 0.68,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-26",
      "Autres": 0,
      "defaultresourcegroup-par": 0,
      "demouic": 0.5,
      "rghm": 0.68,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-25",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.55,
      "rghm": 0.65,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-24",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.6,
      "rghm": 0.38,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-23",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.72,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-22",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.51,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-21",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.69,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-20",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.72,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-19",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.72,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-18",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.67,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-17",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.71,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-16",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.74,
      "uicdemo": 0.56,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-15",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.78,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-14",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.69,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-13",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.74,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-12",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.72,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-11",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.65,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-10",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.7,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-09",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.7,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-08",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.71,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-07",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.7,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-06",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.71,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-05",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.67,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-04",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.7,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-03",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.71,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-02",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.77,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-09-01",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 2.52,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-31",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 1.31,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-30",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.74,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-29",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.75,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-28",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.72,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-27",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.71,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-26",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.7,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-25",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.67,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-24",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.52,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-23",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-22",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-21",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.51,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-20",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.48,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-19",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-18",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.51,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-17",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-16",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-15",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.48,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-14",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.48,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-13",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.48,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-12",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.5,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-11",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.5,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-10",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-09",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.48,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-08",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.48,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-07",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-06",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.5,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-05",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.49,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-04",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 1.06,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-03",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-02",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-08-01",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-31",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-30",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-29",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-28",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-27",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-26",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-25",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-24",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-23",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.45,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-22",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-21",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-20",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-19",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-18",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-17",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-16",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-15",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-14",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-13",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-12",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-11",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-10",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-09",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-08",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.98,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-07",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.53,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-06",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-05",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-04",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-03",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-02",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-07-01",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-30",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-29",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-28",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-27",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-26",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-25",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-24",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-23",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-22",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-21",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-20",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-19",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-18",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-17",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-16",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-15",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.42,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-14",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-13",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-12",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-11",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.77,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-10",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-09",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-08",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-07",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-06",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-05",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.01,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-04",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-03",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-02",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-06-01",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-31",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-30",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-29",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.57,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-28",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0.11,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-27",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-26",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
    {
      "period": "2020-05-25",
      "Autres": 0,
      "demouic": 0,
    },
  ],
  "data_groups": [
    "defaultresourcegroup-par",
    "rdzrg10",
    "uicdemo",
    "rghm",
    "demouic",
  ],
};


stacked_bar_chart_d3js(
  data.column_chart_data,
  $('#column_chart_cost_per_trend').width(),
  $('#column_chart_cost_per_trend').height() - 30,
  '#column_chart_cost_per_trend',
  data.data_groups
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="column_chart_cost_per_trend" style="height: 320px;"></div>
```

Comment: Your `jsFiddle` is over 1300 lines of code. That is way too much to make anyone understand. When asking questions on SO, be sure to remove as much fluff as possible, like the legend, tooltips, etc, so only a [mre] remains

Comment: I could resolve the issue by filtering the dates : 
`var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickValues(x.domain().filter(d => (d.includes("-15"))));`

Comment: You could, but that doesn't solve the underlying problem

Answer (score 1):

You're using `scaleBand`, which is for categorical data and assumes there is absolutely no relationship between the `x` values. So it doesn't sort them, think one is closer to the others, or anything. But your data is not categorical, it's over time. So what you should do is parse your dates, and use `d3.scaleTime` instead:

```js
var data = [
  { "period": "2020-10-28" },
  { "period": "2020-10-27" },
  { "period": "2020-10-26" },
  { "period": "2020-10-25" },
  { "period": "2020-10-24" },
  { "period": "2020-10-23" },
  { "period": "2020-10-22" },
  { "period": "2020-10-21" },
  { "period": "2020-10-20" },
  { "period": "2020-10-19" },
  { "period": "2020-10-18" },
  { "period": "2020-10-17" },
  { "period": "2020-10-16" },
  { "period": "2020-10-15" },
  { "period": "2020-10-14" },
  { "period": "2020-10-13" },
  { "period": "2020-10-12" },
  { "period": "2020-10-11" },
  { "period": "2020-10-10" },
  { "period": "2020-10-09" },
  { "period": "2020-10-08" },
  { "period": "2020-10-07" },
  { "period": "2020-10-06" },
  { "period": "2020-10-05" },
  { "period": "2020-10-04" },
  { "period": "2020-10-03" },
  { "period": "2020-10-02" },
  { "period": "2020-10-01" },
  { "period": "2020-09-30" },
  { "period": "2020-09-29" },
  { "period": "2020-09-28" },
  { "period": "2020-09-27" },
  { "period": "2020-09-26" },
  { "period": "2020-09-25" },
  { "period": "2020-09-24" },
  { "period": "2020-09-23" },
  { "period": "2020-09-22" },
  { "period": "2020-09-21" },
  { "period": "2020-09-20" },
  { "period": "2020-09-19" },
  { "period": "2020-09-18" },
  { "period": "2020-09-17" },
  { "period": "2020-09-16" },
  { "period": "2020-09-15" },
  { "period": "2020-09-14" },
  { "period": "2020-09-13" },
  { "period": "2020-09-12" },
  { "period": "2020-09-11" },
  { "period": "2020-09-10" },
  { "period": "2020-09-09" },
  { "period": "2020-09-08" },
  { "period": "2020-09-07" },
  { "period": "2020-09-06" },
  { "period": "2020-09-05" },
  { "period": "2020-09-04" },
  { "period": "2020-09-03" },
  { "period": "2020-09-02" },
  { "period": "2020-09-01" },
  { "period": "2020-08-31" },
  { "period": "2020-08-30" },
  { "period": "2020-08-29" },
  { "period": "2020-08-28" },
  { "period": "2020-08-27" },
  { "period": "2020-08-26" },
  { "period": "2020-08-25" },
  { "period": "2020-08-24" },
  { "period": "2020-08-23" },
  { "period": "2020-08-22" },
  { "period": "2020-08-21" },
  { "period": "2020-08-20" },
  { "period": "2020-08-19" },
  { "period": "2020-08-18" },
  { "period": "2020-08-17" },
  { "period": "2020-08-16" },
  { "period": "2020-08-15" },
  { "period": "2020-08-14" },
  { "period": "2020-08-13" },
  { "period": "2020-08-12" },
  { "period": "2020-08-11" },
  { "period": "2020-08-10" },
  { "period": "2020-08-09" },
  { "period": "2020-08-08" },
  { "period": "2020-08-07" },
  { "period": "2020-08-06" },
  { "period": "2020-08-05" },
  { "period": "2020-08-04" },
  { "period": "2020-08-03" },
  { "period": "2020-08-02" },
  { "period": "2020-08-01" },
  { "period": "2020-07-31" },
  { "period": "2020-07-30" },
  { "period": "2020-07-29" },
  { "period": "2020-07-28" },
  { "period": "2020-07-27" },
  { "period": "2020-07-26" },
  { "period": "2020-07-25" },
  { "period": "2020-07-24" },
  { "period": "2020-07-23" },
  { "period": "2020-07-22" },
  { "period": "2020-07-21" },
  { "period": "2020-07-20" },
  { "period": "2020-07-19" },
  { "period": "2020-07-18" },
  { "period": "2020-07-17" },
  { "period": "2020-07-16" },
  { "period": "2020-07-15" },
  { "period": "2020-07-14" },
  { "period": "2020-07-13" },
  { "period": "2020-07-12" },
  { "period": "2020-07-11" },
  { "period": "2020-07-10" },
  { "period": "2020-07-09" },
  { "period": "2020-07-08" },
  { "period": "2020-07-07" },
  { "period": "2020-07-06" },
  { "period": "2020-07-05" },
  { "period": "2020-07-04" },
  { "period": "2020-07-03" },
  { "period": "2020-07-02" },
  { "period": "2020-07-01" },
  { "period": "2020-06-30" },
  { "period": "2020-06-29" },
  { "period": "2020-06-28" },
  { "period": "2020-06-27" },
  { "period": "2020-06-26" },
  { "period": "2020-06-25" },
  { "period": "2020-06-24" },
  { "period": "2020-06-23" },
  { "period": "2020-06-22" },
  { "period": "2020-06-21" },
  { "period": "2020-06-20" },
  { "period": "2020-06-19" },
  { "period": "2020-06-18" },
  { "period": "2020-06-17" },
  { "period": "2020-06-16" },
  { "period": "2020-06-15" },
  { "period": "2020-06-14" },
  { "period": "2020-06-13" },
  { "period": "2020-06-12" },
  { "period": "2020-06-11" },
  { "period": "2020-06-10" },
  { "period": "2020-06-09" },
  { "period": "2020-06-08" },
  { "period": "2020-06-07" },
  { "period": "2020-06-06" },
  { "period": "2020-06-05" },
  { "period": "2020-06-04" },
  { "period": "2020-06-03" },
  { "period": "2020-06-02" },
  { "period": "2020-06-01" },
  { "period": "2020-05-31" },
  { "period": "2020-05-30" },
  { "period": "2020-05-29" },
  { "period": "2020-05-28" },
  { "period": "2020-05-27" },
  { "period": "2020-05-26" },
  { "period": "2020-05-25" },
];

var margin = { top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 45 },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("div")
  .append("svg")
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// initialize scales and axis
var scaleBand = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .padding(0.7)
      .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.period; }));

var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var scaleTime = d3.scaleTime()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parser(d.period); }));

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axisX')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height / 2) + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scaleBand));

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axisX')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scaleTime));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="column_chart_cost_per_trend" style="height: 320px;"></div>
```